# How to convert Java object to a Kotlin Multi Platform object

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a Java object. And I have a Kotlin Multi Platform object.
How do I convert this Java object to the Kotlin Multi Platform object?

Java Code:

```
public class JavaRecentItemList extends ObservableBean implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("TotalRowCount")
    int totalRowCount;
}
```

Kotlin Multi Platform Shared code:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class KMMRecentItemList(
    val TotalRowCount: Int? = null
)
```

I have a KMM library that needs a KMMRecentItemList.
i.e:

```
suspend fun foo(itemList: KMMRecentItemList) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just copy it the straightforward way.  Nothing is special about these objects from Kotlin's perspective.

```
 val converted = KMMREcentItemList(javaRecentItemList.totalRowCount)
```

Comment: Actually, I got it by using the GSON library. So I convert it back and forth